# Wider Eclipse Menu

Tags: eclipse, macos, menu

I am using Eclipse Java EE version 2018-09 (4.9.0) on macOS Mojave and the Windows menu isn't wide enough to differentiate between the open windows - all that is visible is the start of the path which makes switching between windows a pain.

I'd like to know whether it is possible to either remove the folders path component of the file name or make the menu wider.

I have removed as much surplus info as I can in Preferences->General->Workspace (all Window title options are turned off)

[image]

Comment: Other applications (ie Chrome) have much wider menus so it isn't a system problem..

Comment: Even with the [Eclipse Title Customizer](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-title-customizer) plug-in this doesn't seem possible. Please report this to Eclipse (I'd like to have the ellipsis points in the middle instead of at the end).

Comment: @howgler I have reported this using Bugzilla on the Eclipse web site. It is bug #541516 if you want to add to it (or see its status) https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=541516